# Relay for Multiple Camera Streams

Tags: raspberry-pi, surveillance-cameras

Is there any open source software available for a Raspberry Pi that will read multiple camera streams on the local network and rebroadcast, keeping them as separate streams?

Comment: please ask at a Linux site since you are asking about a Linux computer

Comment: Requests for software suggestions are probably better asked on [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). You also need to include more details about what protocols you want to use.

Comment: Please revise the question: are multiple camera streams coming as one muxed data stream? The same as Digital Video Broadcast (DVB) data? So you want to demux and split into separate streams?

Answer (score 3):

This will very much depend on what cameras you are using and what protocols they support and where you want to send the collection of streams.

For example I have 2 camera's that support ONVIF which means they have RTSP feeds. I can then use something like ffmpeg to restream as RTMP to NGINX which in turn converts them to HLS/DASH that can be viewed in a browser or streamed to something like a Chromecast.

The depending which video codex the cameras use will determine how hard ffmpeg needs to work and this is likely to be the limiting factor on a Raspberry Pi.

The cameras are both on my private lan and the NGINX machine is exposed to the Internet so I can check on them when away.

The following post on my blog has some more of the technical details: https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/05/03/streaming-camera-to-chromecast/